# Running Nunit Project from console

Tags: selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework

I am new to selenium webdriver C#, I had just jumped into test automation without much knowledge on mechanisms behind automation.

Well, I have automated one process for a web application.

For this, i had created a NUnit project in Xamarin studio. I am able to run my test cases only through IDE i.e Xamarin with clicking- Run button.
 This project folder doesn't have any executable file.

I need to have a way through which i can run the testcases through an executable file asking for inputs(if exist) through console(cmd prompt) so that i can give this Automation project to anyone and all they need to run the testcases is just by running an executable file.

Please can someone guide me to achieve this without having to do any major changes to my existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation on NUnits site located here [Nunit Console Command Line](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2) you should be able to run any tests you have created without making any drastic changes.